# How can one know ahead of time if an airline offers a complementary blanket during a flight?

Tags: air-travel, sleeping, in-flight-services

I wonder how one can know ahead of time (= before going to the airport) whether an airline offers a complementary blanket during a flight.

Comment: Call the airline?

Comment: @littleadv The last time I called an airline customer support I had to wait about 9 hours on a regular day to have someone on the line. So that's a last resort.

Comment: Often mentioned in their blurb about the different ticket classes…

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks. Good to know you're welcome to post it as an answer.

Comment: A much more important question would be whether that blanket is anything you would want to use and the answer is not unlikely to be "no". I would _never_ rely on an airline blanket being clean, there have been absolutely [horrifying](https://twitter.com/nicolebyer/status/842450636562096128) [stories](https://jordanfraser.medium.com/dont-touch-the-airplane-blanket-2c34a1a4d248). I fly a few times a year on transcontinental business class (yay for points hacking) and I never, ever remove the blankets and pillows from their case. I don't want to touch that. I have my own, thanksmuch.

Comment: If they do, make sure you take it to the toilet with you. On one flight, I returned from the toilet to find someome had stolen my blanket. Of course, everyone was asleep.

Comment: @WeatherVane someone took your advice in the first link that chx was mentioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. There seems to be a fair bit of leeway on how the crew handles this on any specific flight. I've certainly been on the exact same flight and sometimes there were blankets and sometimes there were not. You can ask and sometimes they will give you one or the simply don't have any or they just look at you annoyed.

Obviously that depends a lot on the specific flight, airline and class of service but even for a mainline carrier in lie-flat business on a red eye a blanket is not guaranteed.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3UPGv2vFR4&t=395s

This may be also a function of logistics: what's available at point of departure. It's unclear how and when they make the decision to give out blankets or not.